# How can I divide column values in to small buckets then taking moving average of them using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on movie dataset on python

How can I divide the watch_time into “Long” / “Short” buckets, and labels which bucket
each piece of content falls into in addition to this I want to find the running average for each of these buckets and plot graph

Any help much appreciated

```
Movie Table
Team : horror,reality (string)
id : 23556,86455 (int)
Launch Date: 2017-09-08, 2019-02-21 (datetime)

Feature
**ID;**86455,23553 (int)
**Watch_Time** :75,2,20,4 (minutes)(float)
**Rating:**9,5 (int)
```

the dataset is approximately 10M row

Comment: can you provide `df.head().to_dict()` so we can see your actual data set

Comment: I don't have real dataset. I only have sample two three column, two column. I have been told that this dataset has 10m row but I need to solve this problem using only this sample. Basically I need to label 20,4 as short and 75.2 as long and then taking running/moving average of these labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a sample of 20 movies to demonstrate how to do this. Core is [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html). You can also use [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) if you want to define your own buckets.   For purpose of this example I have chosen 3 buckets,  not 2 as noted.  Clearly changing to 2 is just change of parameters to `qcut()`

```py
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'ImdbId': ['tt8579674', 'tt7329656', 'tt7608418', 'tt10006006', 'tt8709036', 'tt2112096', 'tt0445922', 'tt2316204', 'tt0437086', 'tt6189022', 'tt7456310', 'tt0478970', 'tt4154796', 'tt1727824', 'tt6857166', 'tt6823368', 'tt0452625', 'tt3896198', 'tt1846589', 'tt5580036', 'tt4058368'], 
                    'Title': ['1917', '47 Meters Down: Uncaged', 'A Christmas Prince', 'A Christmas Prince: The Royal Baby', 'A Christmas Prince: The Royal Wedding', 'Absolutely Fabulous: The Movie', 'Across the Universe', 'Alien: Covenant', 'Alita: Battle Angel', 'Angel Has Fallen', 'Anna', 'Ant-Man', 'Avengers: Endgame', 'Bohemian Rhapsody', 'Book Club', 'Glass', 'Good Luck Chuck', 'Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2', 'Hunter Killer', 'I, Tonya', 'If There Be Thorns'], 
                    'Runtime': [119, 90, 92, 84, 92, 91, 133, 122, 122, 122, 119, 117, 181, 135, 104, 129, 101, 137, 122, 120, 100]})

# do buckets as ranges and as names
dfa["bucket"] = pd.qcut(dfa["Runtime"], 3)
dfa["named_bucket"] = pd.qcut(dfa["Runtime"], 3, labels=["short","medium","long"])

# generate plots with sensible limits on min/max
dfa.groupby("named_bucket").mean().plot(kind="barh", 
                    xlim=(dfa["Runtime"].min(),dfa["Runtime"].quantile(0.97)))
dfa.groupby("bucket").mean().plot(kind="barh", 
                    xlim=(dfa["Runtime"].min(),dfa["Runtime"].quantile(0.97)))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Rob. This is really helpful!!